# Checkboxes: change bullet points to letters

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to have an org file with 3 checkboxes listed with letters, instead of bullets, but they should remain fully functional.
Instead of:

- [ ] Foo
- [ ] Bar
- [ ] Baz

This:

A [ ] Foo

B [ ] Bar

C [ ] Baz

Is this possible?

Comment: I edited out the second part of the question (re: exporting) since it was really a second question.  If you can't get the export to work as you want, please ask the question again as a separate post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are working with an
`org-mode`
[plain list](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#Plain-lists).
Specifically, you want to use an *ordered* list rather than than
the default *unordered* variety.

When on an item in your plain list, you can rotate through the
bullet styles with <kbd>C-c -</kbd> (that is,
"control C minus"), which invokes `org-ctrl-c-minus`, which, in this
context, invokes `org-cycle-list-bullet`.

Note that the latter takes an optional integer argument to jump
directly to the bullet item you want.  Here's the docstring for more
information:

> `(org-cycle-list-bullet &optional WHICH)`
>
> Cycle through the different itemize/enumerate bullets.
> This cycle the entire list level through the sequence:
>
> `-`  ->  `+`  ->  `*`  ->  `1.`  ->  `1)`
>
> If `WHICH` is a valid string, use that as the new bullet.  If `WHICH`
> is an integer, 0 means `-`, 1 means `+` etc.  If `WHICH` is
> `previous`, cycle backwards.

Note that, if you want to use letters in addition to the bullets
and numbers, you need to set `org-list-allow-alphabetical` to `t`,
so stick `(setq org-list-allow-alphabetical t)` somewhere in your
init file.

If you do set `org-list-allow-alphabetical` then that should be done prior to loading org.el or else you also need to execute `org-element-update-syntax` for that setting to be picked up (as described in the help for that setting).