# Export alphabetical org lists as alphabetical html lists

Tags: org-export

This is a follow up to a [previous question.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32740/checkboxes-change-bullet-points-to-letters)

When exporting an alphabetically sorted org-list to html (`(setq org-list-allow-alphabetical t)`), the list is converted to a numerically sorted list.

Any ideas why that happens? Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Minimum org-file example:

```
A. this
B. is
C. a
D. test
```

And the (relevant part of the) resulting html:

```
<ol class="org-ol">
<li>this</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>test</li>
</ol>
```

Expected output:

```
<ol class="org-ol" type="A">
<li>this</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>test</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: `org-list-allow-alphabetical` only applies to the org-mode source file - if it's set to nil, org will ignore lists that use alphabetical markers. This doesn't have any impact on how lists are exported, which are always numerical. So what you see is expected, not a bug. However, it would be a very nice feature to add!