# Can I have org-mode export outline numbers as letters and/or roman numerals?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, outline

Supposing I have a document structure like:

```
* Heading 1
** Heading a
** Heading b
** Heading c
*** Heading i
*** Heading ii
```

When I do, say, <kbd>M-x</kbd>`org-export-as-html-and-open`, I'd get HTML that shows things as:

```
1 Heading 1
1.1 Heading a
1.2 Heading b
1.3 Heading c
1.3.1 Heading i
1.3.2 Heading ii
```

I'd like this to instead be:

```
1 Heading 1
1.a Heading a
1.b Heading b
1.c Heading c
1.c.i Heading i
1.c.ii Heading ii
```

Or even something fancier like:

```
§ 1 Heading 1
§ 1(A) Heading a
§ 1(B) Heading b
§ 1(C) Heading c
§ 1(C)(i) Heading i
§ 1(C)(ii) Heading ii
```

Is there some way to do this?  I found `org-export-number-to-roman` in the source, but it's not clear to me whether or where it gets called, and I don't see an `org-export-number-to-letter` or similar.

Is there some configuration value that I'm missing, or perhaps a hook that I could create that might be called like `(org-get-outline-numbering-string 1 3 2)` that I could set up to return an arbitrary string of my design such as `1.c.ii` or `1(C)(ii)`, which would then get used, creating HTML such as the following?

```
<h4 id="sec-1-3-2"><span class="section-number-4">1.c.ii</span> Heading ii</h4>
```

I'm open to writing some elisp, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least not using any of the built-in options with org-mode. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32773/export-alphabetical-org-lists-as-alphabetical-html-lists for a similar (unresolved) issue

Comment: Bummer.  Well, in the meantime, I've written some javascript code to find the relevant `<span>` tags and transmogrify them. :)